# Match objects within a nested list using Cypher in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a list of component lists. For each component list I need to match the pno12 to each component and find the structure week associated with that component and then return the highest structure week in each component list. So far this is the query I have but it unwinds

```
with [['000063', '000752', 'R78000', '000854', '000869', '000273', 'P0010', '71700'],
['71700', '000273', '000869', '000063', '000752', 'P0010', 'R78000', '000854']] as names_list
unwind names_list as names
MATCH (p:PNO12{name:"2021110536L4120D110"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:OFFERS]->(n)
WHERE (n.name IN names)
AND NOT (n.from_week IS NULL OR n.to_week IS NULL) 
AND NOT (n.from_week = "000000" OR n.to_week = "000000")
WITH COLLECT(n)+COLLECT(p) AS cmps
UNWIND cmps as c
RETURN c.from_week
ORDER BY c.from_week DESC
LIMIT 1
```

but this gives me gives me 1 result

```
c.from_week
"202045"
```

whereas i need the latest structure week (which is why i sort) per list in the nested list. Does anyone have any hints on how I can acheive this? My original thought was that unwind would run the match separately for each inner list but obviously this is not the case. I'm new at this :)

I don't know if this is a better try but it still doesn't work but might help you get a better idea of what i'm trying to do

```
with [['000063', '000752', 'R78000', '000854', '000869', '000273', 'P0010', '71700'], ['71700', '000273', '000869', '000063', '000752', 'P0010', 'R78000', '000854'] ] as names_list

    unwind names_list as names 

        match (p:pno12{name:"2021110536L4120D110"})
        OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:OFFERS]->(n)
        WHERE (n.name IN names)
        AND NOT (n.from_week IS NULL OR n.to_week IS NULL) 
        AND NOT (n.from_week = "000000" OR n.to_week = "000000") 
        with collect(n.from_week) as weeks
        return names, weeks 
        order by weeks desc limit 1
```

Comment: Can you clarify what this means: "i need i structure week per list in the nested list"? Also, you specify `LIMIT 1`, so naturally you get only one result.

Comment: yeah, i use limit one to get only the latest week, but i need to repeat that for each sub-list somehow

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, idk if this is the perfect answer but it did what i wanted

```
WITH [
  ['000063', '000752', 'R78000', '000854', '000869', '000273', 'P0010', '71700'],
  ['71700', '000273', '000869', '000063', '000752', 'P0010', 'R78000', '000854']
] as names_list
UNWIND names_list as names 
MATCH (p:PNO12{{name:"2021110536L4120D110"}})
OPTIONAL MATCH (p)-[:OFFERS]->(n)
WHERE (n.name IN ["{'","'.join(names)}"])
  AND NOT (n.from_week IS NULL OR n.to_week IS NULL) 
  AND NOT (n.from_week = "000000" OR n.to_week = "000000")
WITH names AS list, n.from_week AS from_week ORDER BY from_week DESC
RETURN list, collect(from_week)[0] AS weeks
```